# Border-Radius text overflowing

Tags: html, css

You can see the webpage here: http://forumalliance.net/api/clan.php?clan=striking

But as you can see words are breaking and splitting mid way. This the css.

```
#clanDetails{
    text-align:center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #BADA55;
    width:50%;
    margin-left:25%;
    margin-right:25%;
    padding: 10px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}

#intro{
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 3px dashed lightskyblue;
    padding: 6px;
}
```

I tried remove `word-wrap:break-word;`
then the description text over-flows past the border....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this by adding `white-space: pre-wrap;` to your `pre` tag. This will prevent words from wrapping mid-way in your preformatted text:

```
#intro > pre {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```